# Detect browser refresh in Iphone using PHP

Tags: php, iphone

I am trying to detect whether the browser of my website page is refreshed so that can perform some logic.Apparently Its working in all other platforms except Iphone. Any help will be appreciated.Below is the php script that I am using.

```
$pageWasRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';
 
if($pageWasRefreshed ) {
  //do something because page was refreshed;
} else {
  //do nothing;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need this kind of logic? There might be better approaches to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Safari doesn't send a `Cache-Control` header after the refresh (this can happen for several reasons). It is not a good idea to rely on the browser to notify you of an refresh with a header, as browsers may change over time.

A better solution to this problem is to use a session, since it will work regardless of the browser.

```
session_start(); //place it at the start of the PHP document, before anything except headers is send to browser

if (!isset($_SESSION["refresh"]))
    $_SESSION["refresh"] = 0;
$_SESSION["refresh"] = $_SESSION["refresh"] + 1;

if ($_SESSION["refresh"] > 1)
{
    //you refreshed the page!
}
else
{
    //first time
}
```

EDIT: Other solutions to this problem are:

- Using cookies (on server side). This won't work if user has disabled cookies.
- Using javascript code on client side. Here it depends on the problem - the solution via javascript can sometimes be unnecessarily complicated, other times required.